# How do i prevent unnecessary rerendering in React using useMemo or useCallback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´m trying to recreate a dijkstras pathfinding visualizer using react hooks.

The wrapper component is as below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import Node from "../Node/Node";

import "./PathfindingVisualizer.css";

import { dijkstra, getNodesInShortestPathOrder } from "../algorithms/dijkstras";

const START_NODE_ROW = 0;
const START_NODE_COL = 0;
const FINISH_NODE_ROW = 0;
const FINISH_NODE_COL = 3;

const TOTAL_ROWS = 3;
const TOTAL_COLS = 6;

const PathfindingVisualizer = () => {
  const [nodeGrid, setNodeGrid] = useState({
    grid: []
  });

  const mouseIsPressed = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const grid1 = getInitialGrid();
    setNodeGrid({ ...nodeGrid, grid: grid1 });
  }, []);

  const handleMouseDown = useCallback((row, col) => {
    //console.log(newGrid);
    setNodeGrid(prevGrid => ({
      grid: getNewGridWithWallToggled(prevGrid.grid, row, col)
    }));
    mouseIsPressed.current = true;
    //console.log(nodeGrid);
  }, []);

  // function handleMouseDown(row, col) {
  //   const newGrid = getNewGridWithWallToggled(nodeGrid.grid, row, col);
  //  console.log(newGrid);
  //   setNodeGrid({...nodeGrid, nodeGrid[row][col]= newGrid});
  // }

  const handleMouseEnter = useCallback((row, col) => {
    //console.log(mouseIsPressed);
    if (mouseIsPressed.current) {
      setNodeGrid(prevNodeGrid => ({
        ...prevNodeGrid,
        grid: getNewGridWithWallToggled(prevNodeGrid.grid, row, col)
      }));
    }
  }, []);

  const handleMouseUp = useCallback(() => {
    mouseIsPressed.current = false;
  }, []);

  const animateDijkstra = (visitedNodesInOrder, nodesInShortestPathOrder) => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= visitedNodesInOrder.length; i++) {
      if (i === visitedNodesInOrder.length) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          animateShortestPath(nodesInShortestPathOrder);
        }, 10 * i);
        return;
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        const node = visitedNodesInOrder[i];
        document.getElementById(`node-${node.row}-${node.col}`).className =
          "node node-visited";
      }, 10 * i);
    }
  };

  const animateShortestPath = nodesInShortestPathOrder => {
    for (let i = 0; i < nodesInShortestPathOrder.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const node = nodesInShortestPathOrder[i];
        document.getElementById(`node-${node.row}-${node.col}`).className =
          "node node-shortest-path";
      }, 50 * i);
    }
  };

  const visualizeDijkstra = () => {
    const grid = nodeGrid.grid;
    console.log(grid);
    const startNode = grid[START_NODE_ROW][START_NODE_COL];
    const finishNode = grid[FINISH_NODE_ROW][FINISH_NODE_COL];
    const visitedNodesInOrder = dijkstra(grid, startNode, finishNode);
    const nodesInShortestPathOrder = getNodesInShortestPathOrder(finishNode);
    animateDijkstra(visitedNodesInOrder, nodesInShortestPathOrder);
  };

  //console.log(nodeGrid.grid);
  //console.log(visualizeDijkstra());
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={visualizeDijkstra}>
        Visualize Dijkstra´s Algorithm
      </button>
      <div className="grid">
        test
        {nodeGrid.grid.map((row, rowIdx) => {
          return (
            <div className="row" key={rowIdx}>
              {row.map((node, nodeIdx) => {
                const { row, col, isStart, isFinish, isWall } = node;
                return (
                  <Node
                    key={nodeIdx}
                    col={col}
                    row={row}
                    isStart={isStart}
                    isFinish={isFinish}
                    isWall={isWall}
                    onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
                    onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
                    onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PathfindingVisualizer;

//----------------------------------------------------------

const getInitialGrid = () => {
  const grid = [];
  for (let row = 0; row < TOTAL_ROWS; row++) {
    const currentRow = [];
    for (let col = 0; col < TOTAL_COLS; col++) {
      currentRow.push(createNode(col, row));
    }
    grid.push(currentRow);
  }
  return grid;
};

const createNode = (col, row) => {
  return {
    col,
    row,
    isStart: row === START_NODE_ROW && col === START_NODE_COL,
    isFinish: row === FINISH_NODE_ROW && col === FINISH_NODE_COL,
    distance: Infinity,
    isVisited: false,
    isWall: false,
    previousNode: null
  };
};

const getNewGridWithWallToggled = (grid, row, col) => {
  const newGrid = grid.slice();
  const node = newGrid[row][col];
  const newNode = {
    ...node,
    isWall: !node.isWall
  };
  newGrid[row][col] = newNode;
  return newGrid;
};
```

My Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-bird-2f8hc?file=/src/PathfindingVisualizer/PathfindingVisualizer.jsx

VideoTutorial for reference:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msttfIHHkak

On first render a grid is generated from mapping over an two-dimensinal array, including a start node and a finish node.

If you click and drag onto the grid walls are toggled on/off, however this causes the entire grid to be rerendered twice, although only the node that is modified in the process should be rerendered.

I can´t figure out how to only rerender the node if the props that are passed down change.

Comment: This is an amazing question. The fact that you attached a proper working demo really helps. Also in future do add the snippet in your post too and some of the codesandbox link can become state and people may no longer find the post useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your re-rendering were because even though you use useCallback method, you were actually re-creating the functions when nodeGrid changes and hence were not able to leverage the performance optimization from React.memo on `Node` component which is because all your `onMouseDown, onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave` handlers were recreated

Also when you use mouseIsPressed as a state, you were forced to trigger a re-render and recreate callbacks again because of it.

The solutions here is to make use of state update callbacks and also use mouseIsPressed as a ref and not a state

```
const [nodeGrid, setNodeGrid] = useState({
    grid: []
  });

  const mouseIsPressed = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const grid1 = getInitialGrid();
    setNodeGrid({ ...nodeGrid, grid: grid1 });
  }, []);

  const handleMouseDown = useCallback((row, col) => {
    //console.log(newGrid);
    setNodeGrid(prevGrid => ({
      grid: getNewGridWithWallToggled(prevGrid.grid, row, col)
    }));
    mouseIsPressed.current = true;
    //console.log(nodeGrid);
  }, []);

  const handleMouseEnter = useCallback((row, col) => {
    //console.log(mouseIsPressed);
    if (mouseIsPressed.current) {
      setNodeGrid(prevNodeGrid => ({
        ...prevNodeGrid,
        grid: getNewGridWithWallToggled(prevNodeGrid.grid, row, col)
      }));
    }
  }, []);

  const handleMouseUp = useCallback(() => {
    mouseIsPressed.current = false;
  }, []);
```

[**Optimized DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-faraday-bbncd?file=/src/PathfindingVisualizer/PathfindingVisualizer.jsx:420-896)

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. I have also found a problem that occurs while dragging on the grid. If you start dragging and mouseup on a certain node, and then click on the same node again and start dragging the mouse pointer is disabled and continiues to add walls. Do you know whats up with that?